# How can I set up a folder with server specific configs to replace default configs of my app?

Tags: kdb, torq

I want to have a folder which will contain various files which will replace default ones when bouncing the app.

For example. if I have a `example1.csv` which is loaded in `proc1.q`

and `example1.csv`'s path is `/a/b/c/example1.csv`

I want to be able to put `/a/b/temporary/example1.csv` which I can modify and if I bounce `proc1.q` it will be picked up in my app.

I thought the best approach would be using `$PATH`, but my files are not executables.

Another idea would be to create a mapping of file location and filename something like

```
file1.csv | /a/b/c/file1.csv
file2.csv | /a/b/c/file2.csv 
file3.q   | /a/b/file3.q
```

Any suggestions?

The reason for this is that I have certain files which change dynamically for each server the app is running on and I would like to commit daily to gitlab and keep track of the state of the app on each server.

Comment: Do you have control over command line args or environment variables when bouncing the app?

Comment: yes. i do have access to these.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to cmd line as you've suggested then you can use both `.Q.def` and `.Q.opt` to accept command line args with defaults. E.g

```
> cat test.q
show files:.Q.def[`file1`file2`file3!(`$"/a/b/c/file1.csv";`$"/a/b/c/file2.csv";`$"/a/b/file3.q")].Q.opt .z.x;
>
> q test.q
KDB+ 3.5 2020.11.27 Copyright (C) 1993-2020 Kx Systems

file1| /a/b/c/file1.csv
file2| /a/b/c/file2.csv
file3| /a/b/file3.q
q)\\

> q test.q -file1 /a/b/temporary/file1.csv -file3 /a/b/c/d/file3.q
KDB+ 3.5 2020.11.27 Copyright (C) 1993-2020 Kx Systems

file1| /a/b/temporary/file1.csv
file2| /a/b/c/file2.csv
file3| /a/b/c/d/file3.q
```

So you pass in overrides to the cmd line when you need them, otherwise you fall back to the defaults.

You could do something similar by setting environment variables prior to bouncing the instance and pulling in the env variables using `getenv` - if they're blank then revert to defaults.